# Identification of flags in a Batman episode

Tags: batman-1966

On Saturday, May 20, 2023 I saw a Batman episode.  It was "Fine Feathered Finks" from January 19, 1966.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_Feathered_Finks

It opened with street scenes of downtown Gotham City, presumably filmed in downtown Los Angeles.  One big building had two flags jutting out from about the second floor.  The flags were white, and each flag had a small red shield in the center.  There seemed to be a white bend or bend sinister in each shield.

The following video shows the establishing shot, but they are not particularly easy to see:

Can anyone identify those flags?

[image: screenshot of the street with flags]

Comment: An image would help immensely here.

Comment: I'll try to get a screenshot later, but from a brief viewing on youtube it looks like a red shield with yellow bend sinister.

Comment: @Joachim people are arguing that it is unclear without an image.  Its not a rule that is being broken here, an image is not *required*, but people are arguing the question is unanswerable without an image.

Comment: I couldn't come closer to the image I added, if it's *not* ok, please remove it

Comment: I don't think LA had a subway system in the 60s.  So this means this is probably New York City, Chicago, Boston, Philadelphia, or Cleveland.

Comment: @iandotkelly : LA had its first [subway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subway_(restaurant)#:~:text=The%20first%20Subway%20on%20the,Fresno%2C%20California%2C%20in%201978.) after 1978 (1st in CA was Fresno) and its second [subway](https://www.dailynews.com/2018/01/29/can-you-believe-los-angeless-first-subway-is-25-years-old/) in 1993 :)

Comment: I don't know about the flags, but that is most likely Fifth Ave at 42nd street (at 0:14) in the video (https://www.alamy.com/1960s-historical-picture-shows-new-yorkers-in-the-financia-or-banking-district-of-new-york-city-wall-street-and-a-billboard-for-three-us-saving-banks-the-seamans-bank-for-savings-the-bowery-savings-bank-and-the-emigrant-industrial-savings-bank-image221038767.html) (https://www.gettyimages.dk/detail/news-photo/1950s-traffic-pedestrians-intersection-fifth-avenue-42nd-news-photo/604434039) The flag on the left may be on 500 Fifth Ave.

Comment: Batman has been available on Blu-ray since 2014, so there should be a better source than a screenshot of a 480p YouTube video. However, this is stock footage, and thus its quality might be not that great on the Blu-ray as well.

Comment: I've never seen or owned a copy of a Batman, sorry, I can't help...